# How to develop a generic bloc and bloc provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

In my flutter application there are so many pages and in most of the pages I send post requests to fetch a list of Objects and I have to use a lot of bloc and bloc provider classes to do so. Is there any way to develop a generic bloc provider with the generic bloc, so that I can use it in all of my pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use or reference source code of the following two package 
https://pub.dev/packages/generic_bloc_provider 
A generic BloC Provider for your Flutter apps.
code snippet

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: AppBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Yo Sleep',
        home: MainPage(),
        initialRoute: 'main',
        routes: {
          'main': (context) => MainPage(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appBloc = BlocProvider.of<AppBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Header(),
            RecordList(appBloc),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc
A Flutter package that helps implement the BLoC pattern.